# Mostrar campos de uma entidade em uma View diferente

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Tenho uma entidade *Acadêmico* que possui uma *Professor*, quero que na View de detalhes do *Acadêmico* seja apresentado o professor responsável por ele, ou seja, o *Professor* que pertence a esse *Acadêmico*.

O código que já estou utilizando é esse:

Model do professor:

```
 public class Professor : RepositorioBase<Professor>
 {
    [Key]
    public int IdProfessor { get; set; }

    public List<Academico> Academicos { get; set; }

    public Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Matrícula")]
    public int Matricula { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "E-mail em formato inválido.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data de cadastro")]
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Atívo")]
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Estagiário")]
    public int IdAcademico { get; set; }
}
```

Model do acadêmico:

```
 public class Academico : RepositorioBase<Academico>
 {
    [Key]
    public int IdAcademico { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Matrícula")]
    public int Matricula { get; set; }

    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "E-mail em formato inválido.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Data de cadastro")]
    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Atívo")]
    public bool Ativo { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Professor orientador")]
    public int IdProfessor { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Pacientes")]
    public List<Paciente> Pacientes { get; set; }

    public virtual Professor Professor { get; set; }
}
```

View de detalhes do acadêmico:

```
<div id="main" class="container-fluid">
<h3 class="page-header"> Detalhes de @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nome)</h3>
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Matricula)</strong></p>
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Matricula)</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Professor.Nome)</strong></p>
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Professor.Nome)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)</strong></p>
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Nome)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)</strong></p>
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataCadastro)</strong></p>
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DataCadastro)</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <p><strong>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Ativo)</strong></p>
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Ativo)</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller de acadêmico:

```
 public class AcademicoController : Controller
{
    private PepContext db = new PepContext();

    // GET: Academico
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var academicos = db.Academicos.Include(a => a.Professor);
        return View(academicos.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Academico/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Academico academico = db.Academicos.Find(id);
        if (academico == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(academico);
    }

    // GET: Academico/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.IdProfessor = new SelectList(db.Professores, "IdProfessor", "Nome");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Academico/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "IdAcademico,Matricula,Nome,Email,DataCadastro,Ativo,IdProfessor,IdPaciente")] Academico academico)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Academicos.Add(academico);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.IdProfessor = new SelectList(db.Professores, "IdProfessor", "Nome", academico.IdProfessor);
        return View(academico);
    }

    // GET: Academico/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Academico academico = db.Academicos.Find(id);
        if (academico == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.IdProfessor = new SelectList(db.Professores, "IdProfessor", "Nome", academico.IdProfessor);
        return View(academico);
    }

    // POST: Academico/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "IdAcademico,Matricula,Nome,Email,DataCadastro,Ativo,IdProfessor,IdPaciente")] Academico academico)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(academico).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.IdProfessor = new SelectList(db.Professores, "IdProfessor", "Nome", academico.IdProfessor);
        return View(academico);
    }

    // GET: Academico/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Academico academico = db.Academicos.Find(id);
        if (academico == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(academico);
    }

    // POST: Academico/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Academico academico = db.Academicos.Find(id);
        db.Academicos.Remove(academico);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Comment: Por que não cria uma propriedade de navegação?

Comment: Onde posso encontrar exemplos ?

Comment: Você usa Entity Framework?

Comment: Estou usando sim

Comment: Veja minha resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como você está usando Entity Framework, isso é bem simples de se fazer.

Você pode usar a [propriedade de navegação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/navigation-property) `Professor` que existe em `Academico`.

Para mostrar, você pode fazer o seguinte na *view*:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <p>@Model.Professor.Nome</p>
</div>
```

Comment: No caso de eu querer apresentar as lista de Acadêmicos que o pertence ao professor, como pode ser feito ?